# How to use my own created template in homeland wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I started wordking with the Homeland wordpresss theme. And I have a question. I have created my own template but when I go to any page to use a templat, the one I've created does not appear. Any ides why ?

Comment: How you can create a template can you read here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: The problem is that I can create it but it does not apper in the dropdown menu under Template options when I want to use it.

Comment: Do you have a comment line in your template file?

Comment: I don't need to upload a file, my theme allows me to create it in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making a page template make sure you have this code running at the [top:](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

If you are making a template for a post,custom post type, category or taxonomy, make sure you are using the correct wordpress naming structure.

[single-post.php

single-custom-post-type.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)
etc...